# Will v2 of the Microsoft Graph API support accessing OneNote consumer notebooks on OneDrive?

Tags: onenote, microsoft-graph-api

Will access to consumer OneNote notebooks stored on OneDrive be supported via the Microsoft Graph anytime soon? I finally realized this is [not yet supported](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/notes) after failing to provide correct authorization scopes.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your feedback. We are looking into it. Please feel free to add this to https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis